# Can't insert NULL into varbinary column using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, varbinary

I have code that updates a record via LINQ to SQL:

```
dc.ClCxDemographicFileAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(new MasterDataContext.ClCxDemographicFileAttachment()
{
    ...
    FileData = characteristicDataFileAttachment.FileData,
});
```

The FileData column in the ClCxDemographicFileAttachment table is VARBINARY(MAX) and nullable in the SQL table and the column/property in the DataContext is System.Data.Linq.Binary.

The problem is that if I set the FileData property to null, LINQ generates an empty byte[] for that column (0x) instead of NULL. I want the latter. How do I fix this?

Comment: What are the data types for `FileData` property and `characteristicDataFileAttachment.FileData`?

Comment: The former is System.Data.Linq.Binary, the latter is byte[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use a data type of `byte[]` instead of `System.Data.Linq.Binary` otherwise some implicit conversion will take place and you will not get a null entry in your database.

Answer (score 1):

DavidG, not sure why you deleted your comment, but you were right. I simply needed to change the FileData column in the DataContext from System.Data.Linq.Binary to System.Byte[]. Not sure why it was the former in the first place.

Comment: I was writing an answer and got called away :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing an inline if that returns a DBNull.Value if the result is an empty byte array (pseudocode):

```
FileData = characteristicDataFileAttachment.FileData == emptyByteArray ? DBNull.Value : characteristicDataFileAttachment.FileData, ...
```

Alternatively you could store this in a variable if you do not like inline ifs.